# connect biometrics zkemkeeper using asp mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sdk, zkteco, zkemkeeper

i hope to all good.
So i'm working on Project using ASP.Net MVC by C# language and i want to integrate  biometric fingerprint machine"ZKTECO model k30" after searching i found must using the zkemkeeper SDK but the SDK for windows application any ideas for how i can make connect between the machine and my ASP project so i can get the attend logs from the machine with code sample please. by the way the finger print device is connected to the computer by USB

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
class SurroundingClass
{
    private var IsDeviceConnected = false;

    private CZKEM objZkeeper = new CZKEM();
    private int iMachineNumber;
    private void ConnectBiometric()
    {
        IsDeviceConnected = objZkeeper.Connect_Net(BiometricIP.Text, BiometricPORT.Text);
        int idwErrorCode;
        if (IsDeviceConnected == true)
        {
            BiometricStatus.Text = "Current State:Connected";
            iMachineNumber = BiometricID.Text;
            objZkeeper.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535);
            BiometricStatus.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        }
        else
        {
            objZkeeper.GetLastError(idwErrorCode);
            BiometricStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            BiometricStatus.Text = ("Unable to connect the device,ErrorCode=" + idwErrorCode);
        }
    }
}
```

class SurroundingClass
{
private var IsDeviceConnected = false;

```
private CZKEM objZkeeper = new CZKEM();
private int iMachineNumber;
private void ConnectBiometric()
{
    IsDeviceConnected = objZkeeper.Connect_Net(BiometricIP.Text, BiometricPORT.Text);
    int idwErrorCode;
    if (IsDeviceConnected == true)
    {
        BiometricStatus.Text = "Current State:Connected";
        iMachineNumber = BiometricID.Text;
        objZkeeper.RegEvent(iMachineNumber, 65535);
        BiometricStatus.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    }
    else
    {
        objZkeeper.GetLastError(idwErrorCode);
        BiometricStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        BiometricStatus.Text = ("Unable to connect the device,ErrorCode=" + idwErrorCode);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).